# Meteor collection2 deny rules : grant full permissions to the server

Tags: collections, meteor, meteor-collection2

I have a user collection with some deny update rules :

```
// The roles object
Schema.roles = new SimpleSchema({
    maker: {
        type: Boolean,
        denyUpdate: true
    },
    admin: {
        type: Boolean,
        denyUpdate: true
    }
});
```

Those datas are in the user profile. And obviously, I don't want the random user to be able to modify `profile.roles.admin`. But the admin user should be able to.

It works partially : the user cannot modify this boolean. But it should be possible to modify it from the following server side code.

```
Meteor.users.update({_id: targetID'}, {$set: {'profile.roles.admin': true}});
```

Is there a way to tell `collection2` to trust the code from the server ?

---

EDIT : the answer

---

Thanks to the answer below, here's the code I use now for my schema :

```
admin: {
    type: Boolean,
    autoValue: function() {
        // If the code is not from the server (isFromTrustedCode)
        // unset the update
        if(!this.isFromTrustedCode)
            this.unset();
    }
}
```

The `isFromTrustedCode` boolean tell if the code should be trusted. Simple. By the way, the `autoValue` option return a complete object about the update (or insert or set or upsert) action. Here are the parametters :

```
isSet: true
unset: [Function]
value: true
operator: '$set'
field: [Function]
siblingField: [Function]
isInsert: false
isUpdate: true
isUpsert: false
userId: null
isFromTrustedCode: true
```

So it is possible to have a really fine-grained management of the writing rights rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As provided in the official [documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2/#inserting-or-updating-without-validating), you can bypass validation using a simple option:

> To skip validation, use the `validate: false` option when calling `insert` or `update`. On the client (untrusted code), this will skip only client-side validation. On the server (trusted code), it will skip all validation.

But if you want more fine-grained control, instead of using a `denyUpdate`, you can use a `custom` validation type which has a `this` context with a `isFromTrustedCode` property which is `true` when called on the server.

Comment: I want fine grained control. The syntax of the `autovalue` option seems complex. But it seems to be what I need. Thank you.

Comment: Your welcome. Autovalue is also great, but you'll find that [custom validation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#custom) is even more powerful and versatile.